# Using mongodb, how can I remove an object from an array based on one of its properties?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection containing an array of objects, and I'd like to remove one or more of the array objects based on their properties.

Example document from my collection:

```
nickname: "Bob",
isLibrarian: false,
region: "South America",
favoriteBooks: [
    {
        title: "Treasure Island",
        author: "Robert Louis Stevenson"
    },
    {
        title: "The Great Gatsby",
        author: "F. Scott Fitzgerald"
    },
    {
        title: "Kidnapped",
        author: "Robert Louis Stevenson"
    }
]
```

In this example, how do I remove, from each of the documents in my collection, all objects within the favoriteBook array whose author matches "Robert Louis Stevenson"?

So that afterwards this user document would be

```
nickname: "Bob",
isLibrarian: false,
region: "South America",
favoriteBooks: [
    {
        title: "The Great Gatsby",
        author: "F. Scott Fitzgerald"
    }
]
```

and other documents in the collection would be equally trimmed of books by Stevenson.

Thank you in advance for any insight!  I love MongoDB but I'm wondering if I've bitten off more than I can chew here...

Answer (score 2):

The below line of mongodb will help you to delete the books that matches a particular author

```
db.collection.update(
   {},
   {$pull:{favoriteBooks:{author:"Robert Louis Stevenson"}}},
   {multi:true}
);
```

Comment: added multi:true since OP specified this should be done to all documents in the collection, also formatted the code.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  The book objects remain within the favoriteBooks array.

Comment: Oops, it does work after all!  At least in this contrived example.  Now to figure out why it doesn't work with my more complex collection (constructed using the same structure).  Thanks!